# Exactly what is the definition of Ubuntu's airplane mode?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I am trying to understand what Ubuntu's airplane mode is, not in concept but in implementation. Aside from the visual indication of it in the GUI, exactly how is this state defined? Is it defined simply as all rfkill-managed RF devices being soft blocked at the same time or is that coincidental to an airplane mode state variable saved elsewhere? I know about Network Manager's `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` file, but there's nothing in there about airplane mode and I haven't found any other state file yet.

Answer (score 0):

from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FlightMode

> Flight Mode ( aka "Airplane Mode" ) is a global control that can be used to turn all transmitting-capable radios on the system off at one time. In the case of a phone, this can include:
>
> Wi-Fi
>   Bluetooth
>   C>ellular
>   NFC
>   GPS ( on some devices GPS is blocked, but as it's a non-transmitting device, this doesn't make much sense )
>   Once airplane mode is enabled, certain radios are allowed to be re-enabled (Wi-Fi, Bluetooth), however the re-enabling the cellular radio is not possible while airplane mode is active. When airplane mode is disabled, any radios that were disabled when airplane mode was activated, will be re-enabled.

See the above link for further information.

Comment: I've tried to clarify in my question that I'm looking for the technical implementation definition, not a conceptual definition. A practical use of the answer should be that from the command line I can determine whether the system is in airplane mode or not and can change that state. I was expecting to find this as a state variable in a file some place, but have not so far.